# copy table to table data from one db to another within aws postgres rds

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have a aws postgres rds, under this have two DBs, so I want to import one database table data to another database table mean table to table data transfer, but here facing the error like constraint and fkey error while importing the table data from one table to another. I heard some XML data file solution for this to export and import the same from one table to another but not sure about this option,. 
Can suggest if anyone have done something similar for aws postgres rds.
trying below option to dump and restore from one DB table to another DB table under AWS postgres RDS but getting error.

```
pg_dump -h <dns name> -U <user name> -p 5432 -t <table name> -d <db a> -f bkp.sql -v
psql -h <dns name> -U <user name> -p 5432 --table <table name> -d <db b>-f bkp.xml -verbose
```

facing below error

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
set_config 
------------
(1 row)
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
psql:bkpq.bkp:42: ERROR:  relation "testtable" already exists
ALTER TABLE
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
COMMENT
psql:bkpq.bkp:154: ERROR:  relation "testtable _id_seq" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
psql:bkpq.bkp:253: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "testtable _pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(84) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY testtable, line 1
 setval 
--------
    129
(1 row)
psql:bkpq.bkp:268: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "testtable " are not allowed
psql:bkpq.bkp:276: ERROR:  relation "testtable _unique_name" already exists
psql:bkpq.bkp:283: ERROR:  relation "testtable_process_platform_process_id_index" already exists
psql:bkpq.bkp:290: ERROR:  relation "testtable _process_platform_process_type_id_index" already exists
psql:bkpq.bkp:298: ERROR:  constraint "testtable _process_create_uid_fkey" for relation "" already exists
psql:bkpq.bkp:306: ERROR:  constraint "testtable _process_partner_process_model_id_fkey" for relation "testtable" already exists
psql:bkpq.bkp:314: ERROR:  constraint "testtable _process_product_template_process_model_id_fkey" for relation "testtable" already exists
psql:bkpq.bkp:322: ERROR:  constraint "testtable _process_quote_item_wizard_process_config_model_id_fkey" for relation "testtable" already exists
psql:bkpq.bkp:330: ERROR:  constraint " testtable_process_type_id_fkey" for relation "testtable" already exists
psql:bkpq.bkp:338: ERROR:  constraint "testtable _process_write_uid_fkey" for relation "testtable " already exists
GRANT
GRANT
GRANT
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a problem with the sequence, you can try and repair by [manually setting the next value](https://hcmc.uvic.ca/blogs/index.php/how_to_fix_postgresql_error_duplicate_ke?blog=22)

Comment: actually i have a lot of tables in first database which need to copy in second database'table with same name as we have the name in database one table and i am facing this error for every tables which copying from one db to another.not sure how to do it.

Comment: my advise is to try and fix it only for one table. Once you know it works, fix it for the rest. Give a try to the solution I linked and see if it helps